# Ag-Grid - Column Tool Panel - hide group

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

[Column Tool Panel Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScFOa.png)

In the image provided above, you can observe that there are two distinct groups under the "Column section", namely "participant" and "game of choice."

I am seeking a toggle function that, when set to "false," will refrain from rendering the aforementioned groups within the Document Object Model (DOM). Conversely, when this function is set to "true," it should render these groups in the DOM.

is their any function like this in AG-grid or we have to do it manually

removing and adding back the element from array which is sent to the Column Chooser

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to set your column definitions each time.

This is how we change the visibility of athlete column in Columns Tool Panel

```
const toggleAthleteColumn = useCallback(() => {
  var columnDefs = gridRef.current.api.getColumnDefs();
  columnDefs.forEach(function (colDef, index) {
    if (colDef.colId === 'athlete') {
      colDef.suppressColumnsToolPanel = !colDef.suppressColumnsToolPanel;
    }
  });
  gridRef.current.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
}, []);
```

Click on the 'Toggle Athlete Column' button to see it in action: https://plnkr.co/edit/EgqBuTnm9gAUgGKl?preview